# storing 'object'

Tags: python, pytables

Does PyTables support storing Python objects?
something like this :

```
dtype = np.dtype([('Name', '|S2'), ('objValue', object)])
data = np.zeros(3, dtype)
file.createArray(box3,'complicated',data)
```

I get error when trying to do this of course...
How to properly store arrays of objects?Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module if you want to store complicated data somewhere it isn't supported by the library in question.

Comment: It's a pity...Thank's for your answer

Comment: Note that pickle has all the problems of an implicit serialization format (namely that it is potentially wrong) and that reading stuff with pickle can execute arbitrary code (introducing a potential huge security hole).

Comment: pickle is poor at handling large data e.g. large numpy arrays. The joblib package works around that by specializing pickle's handling of such arrays.

Answer (score 5):

You can save generic Python object with Pytables:

```
>>> dtype = np.dtype([('Name', '|S2'), ('objValue', object)])
>>> data = np.zeros(3, dtype)
>>> file = tables.openFile('/tmp/test.h5', 'w')
>>> myobjects = file.createVLArray(file.root, 'myobjects', tables.ObjectAtom())
>>> myobjects.append(data)
>>> myobjects[0]
array([('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0)], 
      dtype=[('Name', '|S2'), ('objValue', '|O8')])
```

However, this will use pickle (cPickle in fact) behind the scenes, so you won't be able to access these objects from other languages (pickle is a serialization format only supported by Python itself).