# How to save a Python dtype('O') in an HDF5

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

According to this [link](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/wiki/FAQ) the NumPy generic object ("O") datatype is not supported by h5py but I really need to fine a way to store my object. I have designed my file and already stored other datatypes into it and don't wanna move to other data strcuture. does anybody know a trick in order to store this datatype into 
h5py?
currently I am using this line of code which give me an error `currentgroup.create_dataset("class", data=allClass)`

Comment: PyTables supports python objects. You could try that. [storing 'object'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104812/storing-object)

Comment: @M4rtini http://www.shocksolution.com/2010/01/storing-large-numpy-arrays-on-disk-python-pickle-vs-hdf5adsf/

Comment: Are your datasets so huge that you run out of memory when trying that solution?

Comment: right now no, but in future it is possible.

Comment: What kinds of objects are in your arrays?  Technically a dtype=object array is an array of pointers - pointers to almost anything, including Python functions.  How are those supposed to be represented in a file that can be shared with FORTRAN programs?

Comment: @hpaulj classifier (LDA classfier http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html)

Comment: I'd suggest asking an issue at the Github repository for that project: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues  A class like that needs to specify its own way of 'pickling' itself or its data, so it can be written to a file.